# Merge rows with pandas and append the different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

> | CONTACT_ID | COMPANY_ID | FIRST_NAME | SURNAME | EMAIL | COMPANY_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 8 | Martin | GERARD | martin.gerard@gmail.com | BIG COMPANY |
> | 1 | 87 | Martin | GERARD | martin.gerard@gmail.com | LITTLE COMPANY |
> | 30 | 12 | Jean | DUPOND | jean.dupond@aol.com | MEGA COMPANY |

I'd like to use pandas to convert it like so :

> | CONTACT_ID | FIRST_NAME | SURNAME | EMAIL | COMPANY_ID_1 | COMPANY_NAME_1 | COMPANY_ID_2 | COMPANY_NAME_2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Martin | GERARD | martin.gerard@gmail.com | 8 | BIGCOMPANY | 87 | LITTLECOMPANY |
> | 30 | Jean | DUPOND | jean.dupond@aol.com | 12 | MEGA COMPANY |  |  |

One contact can even have more than two companies.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into groupby()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of columns used for create groups, then converte them to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), flatten `MultiIndex` and last convert levels from list to columns:

```
cols = ['CONTACT_ID','FIRST_NAME','SURNAME','EMAIL']

df = (df.set_index([*cols, df.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1)])
        .unstack(fill_value='')
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1,sort_remaining=False))

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   CONTACT_ID FIRST_NAME SURNAME                    EMAIL COMPANY_ID_1  \
0           1     Martin  GERARD  martin.gerard@gmail.com            8   
1          30       Jean  DUPOND      jean.dupond@aol.com           12   

  COMPANY_NAME_1 COMPANY_ID_2  COMPANY_NAME_2  
0    BIG COMPANY           87  LITTLE COMPANY  
1   MEGA COMPANY
```